# LVM issues when adding a newly-carved LUN from a Clariion - pvcreate fails

Tags: lvm, rhel4, lun, multipath

This seems to be a semi-common issue asked, but I have not yet found a good solution.

I try the following:

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdc
Can't open /dev/sdc exclusively. Mounted filesystem?
```

This [forum post](http://forums13.itrc.hp.com/service/forums/questionanswer.do?admit=109447627+1280431280436+28353475&threadId=1399355) shows the user's solution to have been to boot off a different image, modify his LVM groups, and then restart normally.

That is not an option for this particular setting.

Output of `multipath -l`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# multipath -l
mpath2 (36006016098122700201a28588e21df11)
[size=200 GB][features="1 queue_if_no_path"][hwhandler="1 emc"]
\_ round-robin 0 [active]
 \_ 0:0:1:0 sdc 8:32 [active]
\_ round-robin 0 [enabled]
 \_ 0:0:0:0 sda 8:0  [active]

mpath3 (36006016098122700ac0475432e9bdf11)
[size=200 GB][features="1 queue_if_no_path"][hwhandler="1 emc"]
\_ round-robin 0 [active]
 \_ 0:0:0:1 sdb 8:16 [active]
\_ round-robin 0 [enabled]
 \_ 0:0:1:1 sdd 8:48 [active]
```

What do I need to do to get past this issue?

`mount | grep sdc` return nothing, and `lsof | grep sdc` shows only `multipath` looking at it (which makes sense since it's a LUN).

Comment: Are you sure /dev/sdc isn't mounted?

Comment: running `mount | grep /dev/sdc` returns blank. Running `lsof | grep sdc` shows only `multipath` to be looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow-up: there were other issues with the extant LVs, which on reboot of the server would not mount, and the contained filesystems were missing.

Not good :-|

..this `pvcreate` issue has been tabled for the time being, as we look to restore from backup, and then *extend* the existing LUN rather than add a new one.

Still want to know why the `pvcreate` was failing, but with other issues at hand, it will have to wait.